# Word that sounds like 'stircus,' means 'frenzied/frenetic

Tags: single-word-requests, australian-english

There's a word people around me used to use a lot, phonetically it would spell **'stercus'** or **'stircus'**, I think.

It was used in a context meaning excitable, frenzied, frenetic, that kind of thing. Like, you could say that:

> Kids who eat lots of sugar tend to go stercus.

I don't know if it's an actual word and I can't find it because I'm butchering the spelling or misremembering how it was said. I'm a native speaker from Australia, if that helps.

Comment: "Starkers", maybe? short for stark, raving mad. (But I'm American so I'm just guessing what it could mean in Australian)

Comment: How about "stir-crazy"?

Comment: @ThePhoton That's the answer.

Comment: How about "boisterous" (*noisy, energetic, and rough*) ?

Comment: @ThePhoton Please post your comment  as an answer. It is clearly correct. Answers go in the answer box.

Comment: Berserk? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/berserk

Comment: @Barmar I think it is used more broadly than that (as shown by OP's [self-answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/607091/240807)). "As crazy as being in stir".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OP here, thanks for all your suggestions.

I called my mother, who is a frequent user of the word. She said it's slang that's been used by her extended family for ages. She believes it to be pretty niche slang, potentially regional.

It's not *starkers* (although a good guess) but essentially, as [Weather Vane](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/240807/weather-vane) said, a derivation of *'stir-crazy'*, meaning the same thing, but just *slangified*. As I said above, the best synonym would be frenetic, and used in the context of someone being high energy, hyperactive, etc.

Always interesting to explore the extent that Australians will attempt to turn everything into slang. Would love to hear if anyone else, especially from QLD, has heard it used.

So, to answer my own question, what I was looking for doesn't exist, at least in established English - **it's just slang, pronounced "stir-cuss"**

Comment: So if "it's not *starkers*", what is it??

Comment: @AakashM It's a slang form of stir crazy. Stir crazy > stircrazy > stirckers.

Comment: I grew up in Melbourne, have lived in Perth and Adelaide. Haven't heard stirkers before. When I saw your question, stir crazy was my first thought, but if somebody had said it out loud I'm not sure I would've known immediately what they meant!

Comment: :) You have to wait another day, but don't forget to accept your self-answer.

Comment: @BugCatcherNakata, furthermore, "stir crazy" specifically means going crazy due to being confined or due to boredom. It doesn't (in its literal meaning) apply to going crazy from eating too much sugar...of course that doesn't keep people from using it for whatever they want, but it's an unlikely guess if you don't know the actual usage.

Comment: Your mom denied it was "starkers"?

Comment: @ThePhoton my intuition is that Australian english speakers would be happy for stir crazy to refer to kids on a sugar high. It fits with the idea of kids 'bouncing off the walls' etc.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- starkers and stirkers sound very different with an Australian accent, starkers is not that common in Australian english anymore, at least in my generation (millenial) and stirkers is a natural abbreviation of stir crazy.

Answer (score 18):

I'm not Australian, but I suspect the word is "starkers", a short form for "stark, raving mad".

Although several online dictionaries give the definition "naked" or "completely naked" (i.e. a short form for "stark naked"), Oxford Languages (accessed through a google search for "starkers definition") gives as a second definition:

> 2. mad; crazy.
>
> "his lifestyle would drive me starkers"

Answer (score 2):

What about "**berserk**"?

**Berserk** ([Merriam-Webster](https://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/berserk)): frenzied, crazed — usually used in the phrase "go berserk".

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for **hysterical.** [Cambridge defines it in this sense as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hysterical)

> unable to control your feelings or behaviour because you are extremely frightened, angry, excited, etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't think that's quite it - hysterical has pretty negative connotations, whereas we would use 'stercus' more in the context of crazy, restless, etc. More like nervous excitement.

Comment: It's not uncommon to use it to refer to children acting wild.

Comment: @Barmar, it's also not uncommon to use it to refer to the parents of children acting wild.

Comment: @ThePhoton But be careful using it when referring to Mom, you may be accused of being a misogynist.

Comment: @Barmar, but you'd be etymologically correct, which is the best kind of correct around here.

Comment: @ThePhoton No, that's the point -- "hysterical" originally meant that they were crazy because they're women (e.g. PMS).

Comment: @Barmar This is, unfortunately, a very common misconception. In the ancient world, yes, the term was used to describe a malady thought to originate in the uterus, hence its etymology. In the 1700s, though, it was redefined to describe a condition known to affect people of both genders; at that time it was already believed to originate in the brain, not in the female reproductive system.

Comment: @alphabet but also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Female_hysteria for a more recent gendered application of the word

Answer (score 0):

It is, as already answered, 'starkers'. I've always known it as 'stark staring bonkers', but that may be a regional thing. Depends also on the accent it's spoken in, so Aussi would allow for a tentative spelling thereof.